# How to show secondary notification icon when using a large icon?

Tags: android, eclipse, push-notification, push

When setting a large icon in the push notification, the secondary notification is empty. In the status bar the app of the application is displayed but when opening to see the notification its empty.

here is the link of the notification that i get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHoxY.jpg

Here is my code:

`new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setTicker(title)                .setContentText(msg).setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));`

If I change the target to android:targetSdkVersion="20" it works. But if using a greater SDK it doesn't display the smallicon

Answer (score 1):

Per the [notification style guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#notification), notification icons must be a flat icon - on Android 5.0+ devices, any non-transparent pixels are changed to solid white as seen by your small icon showing a solid square.